# How to write a pandas or dask function to get the following output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask

I want to create the 'Condition' column based on the following conditions:

- If there is an A and B for a 'Unique group', then condition is True for the whole group
- There can be a single A and multiple B or vice versa and the condition will still be True.
- If there is A and no B or vice versa, the condition for whole 'Unique group' is False

```
+----+--------------+------+-----------+
| ID | Unique Group | Name | CONDITION |
+----+--------------+------+-----------+
|  0 |         4133 | D    | True      |
|  1 |         4133 | A    | True      |
|  2 |         4133 | B    | True      |
|  3 |         4133 | C    | True      |
|  4 |         3187 | A    | False     |
|  5 |         3187 | A    | False     |
|  6 |         3187 | C    | False     |
|  7 |         5788 | A    | True      |
|  8 |         5788 | B    | True      |
+----+--------------+------+-----------+
```

I have a rough idea that once I get the Unique Group and the corresponding condition, I can perform a merge to get the 'Condition' to all the same group id but I'm not sure how to get the condition for a single/particular group ID itself.

Comment: (1) why is this related to dask, and not just to pandas? (2) what if you have a single "A" And a single "B"? I guess the condition is True?

Comment: @Roy2012 it is most likely related to dask if he has lots of data that he can't read into memory with pandas or that is borderline and quickly runs out of memory after a couple of functions, dataframes, etc.

Comment: @DavidErickson Yeah, you're right. I have over 200,000 records. I tried both Roy2012 and Valdi_Bo's answers and they seem to work fine with pandas. I was just gonna try your dask answer. I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both `pandas` AND `dask` try...

```
df1 = df.groupby('Unique Group')['Name'].apply(list).reset_index()
df2 = df.merge(df1, how='left', on='Unique Group',  suffixes=('', '_y'))
df2['Temp'] = True
df2['CONDITION'] = df2['Temp'][df2['Name_y'].apply(lambda x: 'A' in x and 'B' in x)]
df2['CONDITION'] = df2['CONDITION'].fillna(False)
df2 = df2.drop(['Temp', 'Name_y'], axis=1)
```

You can't use `.transform` and `np.where()` with `Dask` to my knowledge... hence the extra code...

For just pandas... try with `.tranform`, `.join`, `str.split` and finally `np.where`

```
df['CONDITION'] = df.groupby('Unique Group')['Name'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x)).str.split(',')
df['CONDITION'] = np.where((df['CONDITION'].apply(lambda x: 'A' in x and 'B' in x)), True, False)
```

---

UPDATE: To dask Answer per comment... not sure what is happening with ALL of your data, but from the sample data provided it worked, but I did receive a warning message... to be safe you should specify data types for columns with `meta=('ID':'int64','Unique Group':'int64', 'Name':'object','Condition':'bool')` or whatever you want the data types to be.

[image]

Comment: Hey David, I tried your answer using dask and I'm getting the following error TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable.

Comment: Vaibhav let me try with dask. I just wrote without testing.

Comment: Worked for me. See updated answer. Can you run line-by-line and let me know where you are receiving the error?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create any plain *pythonic* set, as *Pandas*
has its own methods to deal with such cases.

There is also no need to "multiply" the answer.
Due to *broadcasting* feature, *Pandas* does it on its own,
so the function passed to *transform* can return a **single** value.

So a much simpler solution than the other answer is:

```
df['condition'] = df.groupby('Unique Group').Name.transform(
    lambda grp: grp.str.contains('A').any() and grp.str.contains('B').any())
```

On the other hand, the other solution runs faster than mine.
Your choice which one to apply in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, using transform:

```
def check_a_b(ser):
    s = set(ser)
    if "A" in s and "B" in s:
        return [True] * len(ser)
    else:
        return [False] * len(ser)

df["condition"] = df.groupby("Unique Group")["Name"].transform(check_a_b)
```

The result is:

```
   ID  Unique Group Name  condition
0   0          4133    D       True
1   1          4133    A       True
2   2          4133    B       True
3   3          4133    C       True
4   4          3187    A      False
5   5          3187    A      False
6   6          3187    C      False
7   7          5788    A       True
8   8          5788    B       True
```